# Listing music files by year

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, windows-10, mp3

In Windows 10 File Explorer, in the search bar I can type "year:1937" and it will find all the mp3 files in the currently selected folder and below.

[image]

How do I replicate this search in PowerShell or a BAT file? I'm thinking of creating individual files per year using something similar to the following, but how do I get it to look at the "year" tag within mp3s?

**In Powershell:**

This lists all of the mp3s in the current folder and below and outputs it to the year text file, I just need the filter by "Year: xxxx":

```
for ($i=1900;$i -le 2021;$i++)
{
Get-ChildItem -file -name -filter * -recurse -include *.mp3 | out-file -filepath "e:\Music\$i.txt"
}
```

**In Batch:**

```
for %%i in (19, 20) do for %%j in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) do for %%k in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) do dir /s /a:-d /b *.mp3 > %%i%%j%%k.txt
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: `-Recurse` and `-Include` together produce slow results. You are better off leaving off `-Include` and piping to `Where-Object` for that filtering.

Comment: the audio file meta data is NOT available to the dir command in CMD.exe, nor is it available to `Get-ChildItem`. that is provided by an explorer plugin/addon that allows access to the info. PoSh can get the info via calls to a Shell.Application COM object. it's ugly, tho.

Comment: Apply [get file meta data function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804) or [Capturing and using Meta data from MP3/MP4 files with Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Capturing-and-using-Meta-4f81b7da).

Comment: Thank you for your comments - I've got a couple of ideas to try out!

Comment: In the end, I exported from iTunes and did a bit of sorting out! Thanks for your help though :)